# FileNotFoundException (permission denied) when trying to send file over TCP socket in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, tcp, server, permissions

I am trying to send an audio file over TCP socket to a client on my computer. When the Server function is called it connects to the socket but then throws a FileNotFoundException and says permission denied. I have all the required permissions in my manifest and I really don't know what I am missing.

```js
public class Server extends AsyncTask < File, Void, Void > {

  public Void doInBackground(File...soundFile) {

    System.out.println("server: " + soundFile);

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6669); FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile[0])) {
      if (serverSocket.isBound()) {
        Socket sender = serverSocket.accept();
        OutputStream out = sender.getOutputStream();

        byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
        int count;
        while ((count = in .read(buffer)) != -1)
          out.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("server: shutdown");
    return null;
  }
}
```

The Server method is called in my MainActivity.

```js
Uri Selected = data.getData();
            wholepath = getRealPathFromURI(Selected);
            Toast.makeText(this, wholepath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try{
                File file = new File(wholepath);
                new Server().execute(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

[image: my error]

Thanks for all and any help given.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to read external storage?

Comment: yes i have permissions to read and write external storage

Comment: Does this have to do anything with tcp or sockets? Nothing! You get that message opening a file input stream. Please write a better post.

Comment: `I have all the required permissions in my manifest `. Should we believe that you knkw which permissions are required? Moreover that is not enough for Android 6+.

Comment: You don't have permission to read that file, whatever you may think. NB `serverSocket.isBound()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. There would have been an exception. Don't write pointless code.

Comment: Can you post your Android manifest file as well?